# How to setup the terminal proxy for ubuntu terminal via v2ray

Tags: command-line, networking, proxy, youtube-dl

I have already set up the proxy for Chrome via v2ray and 
it is working fine. But I have failed to set up it for terminal for my Ubuntu 18.04. I tried something like:

```bash
export http_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
export https_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

But still I cannot ping through some website like www.google.com, which is blocked in China. Could someone help me out?

Terminal is the Ubuntu 18.04's default gnome terminal emulator. I need to run some command like `youtube-dl +website address` in the terminal to download videos from YouTube, which means that I need to be able to access YouTube through the terminal first (for example using `ping www.youtube.com` command to transmit some packets and see if it could receive it).

Comment: What do you mean with "terminal"? AFAIK, it is not possible to `ping` through a proxy!

Comment: Terminal is the ubuntu 18.04's default gnome terminal emulator. I need to run some command like "youtube-dl +website address"  in the terminal to download videos from youtube, which means that I need to be able to access youtube through the terminal first(for example using "ping www.youtube.com" command to transmit some packages and see if it could recieve it).

Comment: You can use proxychains package instead.

Answer (score 1):

`youtube-dl` has option to use proxy:

```
youtube-dl --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

or

```
youtube-dl --proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```